# Convert TCHAR array to char array

Tags: character-encoding, visual-c++, tchar

How to convert to `TCHAR[]` to `char[]` ?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159442/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-char-to-from-tchar-in-c-cms

Comment: This will definitely help you:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

Comment: I just change  General -> Character Set := "Use Unioncode Character set" and its now working (char *) tcharr ;

Answer (score 12):

Honestly, I don't know how to do it with arrays but with pointers, Microsoft provides us with some APIs, such as [wctomb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tdk45ff%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [wcstombs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d7tc9zw%28VS.71%29.aspx). First one is less secure than the second one. So I think you can do what you want to achieve with one array-to-pointer and one pointer-to-array casting like;

```
// ... your includes
#include <stdlib.h>
// ... your defines
#define MAX_LEN 100
// ... your codes
// I assume there is no any defined TCHAR array to be converted so far, so I'll create one
TCHAR c_wText[MAX_LEN] = _T("Hello world!");
// Now defining the char pointer to be a buffer for wcstomb/wcstombs
char c_szText[MAX_LEN];
wcstombs(c_szText, c_wText, wcslen(c_wText) + 1);
// ... and you're free to use your char array, c_szText
```

PS: Could not be the best solution but at least it's working and functional.

Answer (score 4):

TCHAR is a Microsoft-specific typedef for either `char` or `wchar_t` (a wide character).

Conversion to char depends on which of these it actually is. If TCHAR is actually a `char`, then you can do a simple cast, but if it is truly a `wchar_t`, you'll need a routine to convert between character sets. See the function [`MultiByteToWideChar()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar).

Comment: I think we need to convert from wchar_t to char so we need WidecharToMultiByte!!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use [wcstombs_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7wzt4be.aspx) ?

Here is the code to show how simple it is.

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 500
...

TCHAR szWideString[MAX_LENGTH];
char szString[MAX_LENGTH];
size_t nNumCharConverted;
wcstombs_s(&nNumCharConverted, szString, MAX_LENGTH,
        szWideString, MAX_LENGTH);
```

Comment: You misspelled 'LENGTH'.

Comment: LENGHT is a constant not a keyword.

Comment: Done, I fixed LENGTH spelling.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the character set (Unicode or ANSI) (wchar_t or char), so if you are using ANSI simply TCHAR will be char without any casting,  but for Unicode, you have to convert from wchar_t to char, you can use [WideCharToMultiByte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215963/how-do-you-properly-use-widechartomultibyte)