# Main only receiving first letters of arguments

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

```
int _tmain(int argc, char** argv)  
    {  
      FILE* file1=fopen(argv[1],"r");  
      FILE* file2=fopen(argv[2],"w");  
    }
```

It seems as if only the first letter of the arguments is received... I don't get why!

```
std::cout<<"Opening "<<strlen(argv[1])<<" and writing to "<<strlen(argv[2])<<std::endl;
```

outputs 1 and 1 no matter what. (in MSVC 2010)

Comment: What is `_tmain`? In what environment are you working?

Comment: See the answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. It's phrased differently, and you are not the first developer I've seen stumbling on exactly these symptoms. So this formulation at least should stay IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not `char` it's `wchar_t` when you are compiling with `UNICODE` set.

It is compiled as `wmain`. Linker just does not notice that there is a different signature, because it's "export C" function and it's name does not contain its argument types.

So it should be int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR** argv)

Converting to char is tricky and not always correct - Win32 provided function will only translate the current ANSI codepage correctly.

If you want to use UTF-8 in your application internals then you have to look for the converter elsewhere (such as in [Boost](http://boost.org))

Comment: Would you happen to know how to convert to char?

Comment: @Cenoc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159442/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-char-to-from-tchar-in-c-cms

Comment: Don't convert to `char` at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your argument string is coming in as UNICODE.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895827/what-is-the-difference-between-tmain-and-main-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `char` data type on Windows, it breaks Unicode support. Use the "wide" functions instead. In C++, avoid C's stdio, use file streams instead:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t** argv) {
  if (argc <= 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  const std::wstring arg1 = argv[1];
  const std::wstring arg2 = argv[2];
  std::ifstream file1(arg1.c_str());
  std::ofstream file2(arg2.c_str());
}
```