# Why PathFileExists() not working?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to validate the existence of a file and after some search I think PathFileExists() may fit the job. However, the following code always show the file doesn't exist. To ensure the file really exist, I choose full path of cmd.exe as the test file path. I'm using windows 7 (x64)

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <WinDef.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 

    char path[] = "c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
    LPCTSTR szPath = (LPCTSTR)path;
    if(!PathFileExists(szPath)) 
    { 
        printf("not exist\n");  
    }else{
        printf("exists!\n"); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Can you explain about the problem?

## UPDATE

Spend almost whole afternoon and figure out the problem.
The PathFileExists() function expect second parameter of type `LPCTSTR`.However, the compiler can not correctly convert `char *` to `LPCTSTR` then I include `tchar.h` and using the `TEXT`macro to initialize the pointer. Done. 
LPCTSTR lpPath = TEXT("c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"); [The MSDN reference example code for PathFileExists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is kind of outdated. The reference example used `char *` directly for PathFileExists() and can not pass compile in visual studio 2011 beta. And also , example code missed the `using namespace std;`
Among all, I think @steveha 's answer is closest to the true problem. Thank you all guys.

the final working code look like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <WinDef.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    LPCTSTR lpPath = TEXT("c:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
        if( PathFileExists(lpPath) == FALSE)  
    { 
        printf("not exist\n");  
    }else{
            printf("exists!\n"); 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Sorry foradding the solution here, but I really want to post some thought after a whole aternoon work and hope that helps other newbies.

Comment: Try calling [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) after the failure, to see what went wrong.

Comment: Please don't apologize for adding the solution here; that is *great*.  Now your question will be very helpful for other people who find it here on StackOverflow.  My own answer gave you a clue, but isn't a complete answer, and it's great that you posted a complete answer.  I already gave you +1 but I would give +1 again if I could.

Comment: The reference is not outdated; you can specify whether your application uses single byte or unicode strings in project settings (General > Character Set). This affects whether macros such as LPCTSTR expand to `wchar_t const*` or `char const*`, and most API functions can expand to either `PathFileExistsW` or `PathFileExistsA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you need to convert a `char` string to a `TSTR` and you aren't doing that.

You are using a type cast to coerce a pointer from type `char *` to type `LPCTSTR` but I think that doesn't actually work.  As I understand it, a `TCHAR` is either the same thing as `char` or else it is a "wide char".  I think you must have `TCHAR` set to wide char or else you wouldn't have a problem.

I found a StackOverflow answer that includes information that may help you:

[What is the simplest way to convert char[] to/from tchar[] in C/C++(ms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159442/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-convert-char-to-from-tchar-in-c-cms)

You might try calling `MultiByteToWideChar()` and see if that fixes the problem.