# How to do Latin1-UTF8 encoding change in C++ (maybe with Boost)?

Tags: c++, character-encoding

My source base is mostly using UTF8, but some older library has Windows Latin1 encoded strings hardcoded within it.

I was hoping Boost would have a clear conversion feature, but I did not find such. Do I really need to hand-code such a commonplace solution?

Looking for a portable solution, running on Linux.

([This Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl) is similar, but not quite the same)

**Edit:**  ICU seems to be the right answer, but it's a bit overkill for my needs. I ended up doing string-replace for the known few extended chars that were used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[International Components for Unicode](http://www.icu-project.org) (ICU) does have the solutions you are looking for. Boost can be compiled with support for ICU, e.g. for Boost regular expressions, but precompiled versions of Boost usually don't include it.