# Convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 under Windows and Linux, in C

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I was wondering if there is a recommended 'cross' Windows and Linux method for the purpose of converting strings from UTF-16LE to UTF-8? or one should use different methods for each environment?

I've managed to google few references to 'iconv' , but for somreason I can't find samples of basic conversions, such as - converting a wchar_t UTF-16 to UTF-8.

Anybody can recommend a method that would be 'cross', and if you know of references or a guide with samples, would very appreciate it.

Thanks, Doori Bar

Comment: See this previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I'm afraid it's too low-level for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, this is how I managed to solve the 'cross' windows and linux requirement:

1. Downloaded and installed: `MinGW` , and `MSYS`
2. Downloaded the `libiconv` source package
3. Compiled `libiconv` via `MSYS`.

That's about it.

Answer (score 14):

Change encoding to UTF-8 with PowerShell:

```
Get-Content PATH\temp.txt -Encoding Unicode | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 PATH2\temp.txt
```

Comment: Works great on Windows 2008 R2. BOM is also added.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use ICU,

1. Windows: [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130(VS.85).aspx)
2. Linux: [iconv](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/iconv.3.html) (Glibc)

Answer (score 7):

The open source [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) is very commonly used.

Answer (score 6):

If you have MSYS2 installed then the `iconv` package (which is installed by default) lets you use:

```
 iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 <input.txt >output.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iconv.h>

wchar_t *src = ...; // or char16_t* on non-Windows platforms
int srclen = ...;
char *dst = ...;
int dstlen = ...;
iconv_t conv = iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-16");
iconv(conv, (char*)&src, &srclen, &dst, &dstlen);
iconv_close(conv);
```

Comment: I suppose "UTF-16" and "UTF-8" should switch places.

Comment: Where does iconv... come from? Answer:  #include <iconv.h> – Also, this seems to be Linux specific.

Comment: [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) is a cross-platform library, it is available on many platforms, including Linux.

Answer (score 4):

I have run into this problem too, I solve it by using [boost locale library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/charset_handling.html)

```
try
{           
    std::string utf8 = boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf<char, short>(
                        (short*)wcontent.c_str(), 
                        (short*)(wcontent.c_str() + wcontent.length()));
    content = boost::locale::conv::from_utf(utf8, "ISO-8859-1");
}
catch (boost::locale::conv::conversion_error e)
{
    std::cout << "Fail to convert from UTF-8 to " << toEncoding << "!" << std::endl;
    break;
}
```

The **boost::locale::conv::utf_to_utf** function try to convert from a buffer that encoded by UTF-16LE to UTF-8, 
The **boost::locale::conv::from_utf** function try to convert from a buffer that encoded by UTF-8 to ANSI, make sure the encoding is right(Here I use encoding for Latin-1, ISO-8859-1).

Another reminder is, in Linux std::wstring is 4 bytes long, but in Windows std::wstring is 2 bytes long, so  you would better not use std::wstring to contain UTF-16LE buffer.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [utfcpp](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/), which is a header-only library.

Answer (score 1):

Another portable C possibility to convert string between UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32, wchar - is [mdz_unicode](https://github.com/maxdz-gmbh/mdz_unicode) library.

Answer (score 0):

You can also roll your own, which has several benefits:

1. Not subject to the somewhat restrictive license of iconv
2. No restriction on statically linking to avoid ICU version hell or other dynamic-link headaches
3. Avoid the need to link a very large library (such as icu or boost) (which, if statically linked, can add tens of MB of size to what might otherwise be a very small binary)

Note: the below assumes you have installed [utf8proc](https://github.com/JuliaStrings/utf8proc), which is very compact. however, if you prefer, you can simply use its header file and copy the one `utf8proc_encode_char()` function that this code uses.

utf16le_to_utf8.h:

```
#ifndef UTF16LE_TO_UTF8_H
#define UTF16LE_TO_UTF8_H

enum utf816le_status {
  utf816le_status_ok = 0,
  utf816le_status_malformed_utf6le_input,
  utf816le_status_memory,
  utf816le_status_unencodable,
  utf816le_status_buffsize
};

/*
 * @return converted string, or NULL on error
 * @param str      input string
 * @param len      length (in bytes) of input string
 * @param buff     optional user-provided output buffer. if not provided, the returned
 *                 converted string must be freed by caller using free()
 * @param buffsize length of user-provided buffer, or 0 if no buffer provider
 * @param out_len  pointer to length of converted output, in bytes
 * @param status   pointer to status, set to non-zero in case of error
 */
unsigned char *utf16le_to_utf8(const unsigned char *str, size_t len,
                               unsigned char *buff, size_t buffsize,
                               size_t *out_len,
                               enum utf816le_status *status);

#endif
```

utf16le_to_utf8.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <utf8proc.h>
#include "utf16le_to_utf8.h"

#if defined( __FreeBSD__ ) || defined( __OpenBSD__ ) || defined( __NetBSD__ )
#  include <sys/endian.h>
#elif defined( BSD ) && ( BSD >= 199103 ) || defined( __APPLE__ ) || \
      defined( __CYGWIN32__ ) || defined( __DJGPP__ ) || defined( __osf__ )
#  include <machine/endian.h>
#elif defined( __linux__ ) || defined( __GNUC__ ) || defined( __GNU_LIBRARY__ )
#  if !defined( __MINGW32__ ) && !defined( _AIX )
#    include <endian.h>
#    if !defined( __BEOS__ )
#      include <byteswap.h>
#    endif
#  endif
#endif

static inline uint16_t little_endian_16(uint16_t v) {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
  return v;
#else
  return (v << 8) | (v >> 8);
#endif
}

static utf8proc_int32_t utf16le_next_codepoint(uint16_t *text, unsigned int max_bytes,
                                               unsigned int *bytes_read) {
  uint16_t c1 = little_endian_16(text[0]);
  if (c1 >= 0xd800 && c1 < 0xdc00) {
    if(max_bytes < 4) {
      *bytes_read = 0;
      return 0;
    }
    *bytes_read = 4;
    uint16_t c2 = text[1];
    return ((c1 & 0x3ff) << 10) + (c2 & 0x3ff) + 0x10000;
  }

  if(max_bytes < 2) {
    *bytes_read = 0;
    return 0;
  }
  *bytes_read = 2;
  return c1;
}

unsigned char *utf16le_to_utf8(const unsigned char *str, size_t len,
                               unsigned char *buff, size_t buffsize,
                               size_t *out_len,
                               enum utf816le_status *status) {
  if(!buffsize)
    buff = NULL;
  if(!buff)
    buffsize = 0;
  unsigned char *dst = buff;
  size_t sizeof_dst = buffsize;
  size_t written = 0;

  *status = utf816le_status_ok;
  unsigned char_len;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i+= char_len) {
    utf8proc_int32_t codepoint = utf16le_next_codepoint((uint16_t *)(str + i), len - i, &char_len);
    if(!char_len) { // error! bad utf
      *status = utf816le_status_malformed_utf6le_input;
      break;
    }
    // we need at least 4 bytes to encode to utf8. add 1 for terminal null and 1 for good measure
    if(sizeof_dst < written + 6) {
      if(buffsize > 0) { // user-provided buffer is too small
        *status = utf816le_status_buffsize;
        break;
      }
      size_t new_size = sizeof_dst == 0 ? 64 : sizeof_dst * 2;
      unsigned char *new_dst = realloc(dst, new_size);
      if(!new_dst) { // out of memory!
        *status = utf816le_status_memory;
        break;
      }
      dst = new_dst;
      sizeof_dst = new_size;
    }
    utf8proc_ssize_t want = utf8proc_encode_char(codepoint, dst + written);
    if(!want) { // error
      *status = utf816le_status_unencodable;
      break;
    }
    written += want;
  }
  if(*status == utf816le_status_ok) {
    *out_len = written;
    dst[written] = '\0';
    return dst;
  }
  *out_len = 0;
  if(dst != buff)
    free(dst);
  return NULL;
}
```

which you can use like so:

```
    ...
    unsigned char *converted = utf16le_to_utf8(utf16buff, utf16byte_count, NULL, 0, &output_len, &status);
    if(!converted || !output_len)
      fprintf(stderr, "Error! %i\n", status);
    else
      fprintf(stdout, "Converted to utf8 with length %zu: %s\n", output_len, converted);
    free(converted);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me (taken from [The conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244060/the-conversion-from-utf-16-to-utf-8)):

```c
#include <stdint.h>

// Converts UTF-16 string into UTF-8 string.
// If destination string is NULL returns total number of symbols that would've
// been written (without null terminator). However, when actually writing into
// destination string, it does include it. So, be sure to allocate extra byte
// for destination string.
// Params:
// u16_str      - source UTF-16 string
// u16_str_len  - length of source UTF-16 string
// u8_str       - destination UTF-8 string
// u8_str_size  - size of destination UTF-8 string in bytes
// Return value:
// 0 on success, -1 if encountered invalid surrogate pair, -2 if
// encountered buffer overflow or length of destination UTF-8 string in bytes
// (without including the null terminator).
long int utf16_to_utf8(const uint16_t *u16_str, size_t u16_str_len,
                       uint8_t *u8_str, size_t u8_str_size)
{
    size_t i = 0, j = 0;

    if (!u8_str) {
        u8_str_size = u16_str_len * 4;
    }

    while (i < u16_str_len) {
        uint32_t codepoint = u16_str[i++];

        // check for surrogate pair
        if (codepoint >= 0xD800 && codepoint <= 0xDBFF) {
            uint16_t high_surr = codepoint;
            uint16_t low_surr  = u16_str[i++];

            if (low_surr < 0xDC00 || low_surr > 0xDFFF)
                return -1;

            codepoint = ((high_surr - 0xD800) << 10) +
                        (low_surr - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
        }

        if (codepoint < 0x80) {
            if (j + 1 > u8_str_size) return -2;

            if (u8_str) u8_str[j] = (char)codepoint;

            j++;
        } else if (codepoint < 0x800) {
            if (j + 2 > u8_str_size) return -2;

            if (u8_str) {
                u8_str[j + 0] = 0xC0 | (codepoint >> 6);
                u8_str[j + 1] = 0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3F);
            }

            j += 2;
        } else if (codepoint < 0x10000) {
            if (j + 3 > u8_str_size) return -2;

            if (u8_str) {
                u8_str[j + 0] = 0xE0 | (codepoint >> 12);
                u8_str[j + 1] = 0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F);
                u8_str[j + 2] = 0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3F);
            }

            j += 3;
        } else {
            if (j + 4 > u8_str_size) return -2;

            if (u8_str) {
                u8_str[j + 0] = 0xF0 | (codepoint >> 18);
                u8_str[j + 1] = 0x80 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3F);
                u8_str[j + 2] = 0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3F);
                u8_str[j + 3] = 0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3F);
            }

            j += 4;
        }
    }

    if (u8_str) {
        if (j >= u8_str_size) return -2;
        u8_str[j] = '\0';
    }

    return (long int)j;
}
```

You can test it here: https://godbolt.org/z/coqTEfsK7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).