# What's a small LGPL library for C++ UTF-8/UTF-16 text encoding?

Tags: c++, unicode, stl, utf-8

Need something small and portable. Currently looking at UTF8-CPP but thought that I'd reach out for other suggestions too.

Cheers.

Comment: What do you need to do? A basic encoding and decoding of UTF8 and UTF16 can be written in a couple of lines.

Comment: Covered by a couple of previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867123/convert-utf-16-to-utf-8-under-windows-and-linux-in-c

Comment: With a quick barrage of answers and references - UTF8-CPP remains the winner. Its small (just three header files, all inline code) and has an open license that allows modification and redistribution for anyone.

Comment: Does this need to be portable? Most OSes have non-portable charset conversion routines that you could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8CPP it is, just want to mark this question as done with. Thanks for all the help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

[ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) is an "International Components for Unicode" - portable and open source.

Haven't used it myself, so I can't say how good it is, but I know [others](http://code.google.com/p/google-url/) that do.

Comment: It's a good library for most everything, except binary size. Compiled ICU is ~16MB by itself!

Comment: @Billy: Most of that likely comes from the data library.  It can be customized to further improve its footprint: http://userguide.icu-project.org/icudata#TOC-Reducing-the-Size-of-ICU-s-Data:-Co

Comment: ICU is indeed far too large (maintained by IBM for mammoth projects).

Comment: @Void: Yes, I'm not knocking the library too much. But for most of my apps which MUST be under 500k total (I'm supporting Dial-Up users) the size makes it prohibitive. It's an awesome library, just more than I usually need.

Comment: @Billy: Ouch!  That's a tough maximum size to deal with these days.  I do agree with you.  It is quite large; often after the data library footprint optimizations, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost?](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/codecvt.html) or [short source](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/UTF8.aspx)?

Answer (score -2):

Ironically enough, the best/easiest/most robust way is to wrap Unicode-aware stdlib (C) functions like setlocale(), wprintf() and mbstowcs in your own, application-level) C++ classes. The APIs are portable, and they've been in use for many years.

A few links:

- http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/51836
- http://linuxgazette.net/147/pfeiffer.html

Comment: -1: `setlocale` and `mbstowcs` are entirely *encoding-agnostic*! Here is a [little rant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300804/wchars-encodings-standards-and-portability) of mine on that subject.

Comment: sparkFinder - If UTF8-CPP works for you, cool!  Otherwise I'd strongly urge you to consider wrapping setlocale() and friends.  It's apparently not what the Kool Kids do around here - but it works.  And it works well :)

Comment: @paulsm4: No, it does not work. mbstowcs does not tell you what encoding you are using (and indeed, has no means of changing the encoding). If you are on a platform where you can ensure wcstombs and mbstowcs convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16, good for you. But that's not 99% of platforms. Certainly not Windows or POSIX boxes.