# HTML file fetched using 'wget' reported as binary by 'less'

Tags: http, wget

If I use `wget` to download [this](http://www.aqr.com/ResearchDetails.htm) page:

```
wget http://www.aqr.com/ResearchDetails.htm -O page.html
```

and then attempt to view the page in `less`, less reports the file as being a binary.

```
less page.html 
"page.html" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

These are the response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:8295
Content-Type:text/html
Cteonnt-Length:44064
Date:Sun, 25 Sep 2011 12:15:53 GMT
ETag:"c0859e4e785ecc1:6cd"
Last-Modified:Fri, 19 Aug 2011 14:00:09 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Opening the file in vim works fine.

Any clues as to why less can not handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an UTF-16 encoded file. ([Check with W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aqr.com%2FResearchDetails.htm&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)). You can convert it to UTF-8 with this command:

```
wget http://www.aqr.com/ResearchDetails.htm -q -O - | iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 > page.html
```

`less` usally knows UTF-8.

**edit**:

As @Stephen C reported, `less` in Red Hat supports UTF-16. It looks to me that [Red Hat patched less for UTF-16 support](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638312). On the [official site of the less](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/bugs.html) UTF-16 support currently is an open issue (ref number 282).

Comment: Annoyingly in the HTML meta it is reported as "charset=iso-8859-1" - presumably this is just wrong?

Comment: It's definitely not ISO-8859-1. Maybe it comes from a template or the file was saved accidentally with UTF-16.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is UTF-16 encoded as can be seen with the BOM of `ff ee` in the first two octets:

```
$ od -x page.html | head -1
0000000 feff 003c 0021 0044 004f 0043 0054 0059
```

vim is smarter about it (because it is more Unicode era) than `less`.

**added:**

See [Convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 under Windows and Linux, in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867123/convert-utf-16-to-utf-8-under-windows-and-linux-in-c) for what to do about it. Or use vim to write it back out with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Nice guess, but I think `wget` is not so stupid to produce uncompressed binary data to output.

Comment: @dma_k: right you were, which is why I fixed my answer (that is, your comment applies to a prior edit and I didn't want people to point and laugh because it now makes little sense ;)

Comment: Annoyingly in the HTML meta it is reported as "charset=iso-8859-1" - presumably this is just wrong?

Comment: @msw: No, the answer didn't look ridiculous. By the time I've answered I have the original (different) version, and now all answers are the same – that was funny to observe :) Anyway this question was a simple nut for community.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, if HTML `<meta>` tag gives this information, it is wrong. Web Designers sometimes don't know in the details about the data they deal with.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it works for me.  When I download the file using that file, I get a file that "less" shows me without any questions / problems.  (I use RedHat Fedora 14.)

Second, the "file" command reports "page.html" as:

> page.html: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode HTML document text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators

Maybe the UTF-16 encoding is the cause of the problems.  (But why ... I don't know why it would work with my version of "less" and not yours.)

---

@palacsint's solution works for me:

```
wget http://www.aqr.com/ResearchDetails.htm -q -O - | \
     iconv -f utf-16 -t utf-8 > page.html
```

Comment: "I don't know why it would work with my version of "less" and not yours" - It's Red Hat specific, they patched `less` and [`file` too to support UTF-16](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=235420). Take a look at my updated answer. On my old Debian UTF-16 is not supported by `less` nor `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely this HTML file contains UTF characters and your locale is not set correctly (`export LANG=en_US.UTF8 LESSCHARSET=utf-8`). It may also happen that HTML contains invalid characters.

**EDIT**: After checking the file I clearly see it is UTF-16. So you need to correct your terminal settings correspondingly (although I was able to see the text correctly with UTF8 setting, perhaps my terminal program is smart).