# Convert JNI UTF-16 string to standard C++ UTF-8 string

Tags: c++, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I need to convert a UTF-16 string to a UTF-8 string.

```
const unsigned short *utf16string = ...;
const char *utf8string = convertUTF16toUTF8(utf16string);
```

Can anybody help me find/write the function `const char* convertUTF16toUTF8(const unsigned short* utf16string)`?

The types can't be changed, unfortunately, and I don't have access to C++11. I've been beating my head at this for hours and can't find any solutions.

Please help me. I believe in you, StackOverflow!

P.S. If anybody needs to know, I'm making a game using cocos2d-x and I'm trying to get a string using the JNI callbacks. JNI has a UTF version of the `GetString...` functions, yet these are buggy according to my own experience and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), so I need to convert the strings using the raw functions.

Comment: What environment are you in? There might already be a function in the OS. But otherwise I'd just read in one code-point at a time from the UTF-16 string - potentially over two shorts - and then write it out as UTF-8 chars, then repeat. To allocate the buffer ahead of time you can probably guess it'll be the same size as the UTF-16 or shorter and then reallocate if you hit the limit.

Comment: This code is being used on Android.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I don't have access to it :(

Comment: Is this question related to your problem? Does it help? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867123/convert-utf-16-to-utf-8-under-windows-and-linux-in-c

Comment: http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @dalle you did it! You genius! Post that link as the answer and I'll mark it for you.

Comment: [wcstombs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a simple and small C++ library you could use [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) to convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16.