# Convert UTF-16 to UTF-8

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode, utf

I am current using VC++ 2008 MFC. Due to PostgreSQL doesn't support UTF-16 (Encoding used by Windows for Unicode), I need to convert string from UTF-16 to UTF-8, before store it.

Here is my code snippet.

```
// demo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "demo.h"
#include "Utils.h"
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
    }

    CString utf16 = _T("Hello");
    std::cout << utf16.GetLength() << std::endl;
    CStringA utf8 = UTF8Util::ConvertUTF16ToUTF8(utf16);
    std::cout << utf8.GetLength() << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return nRetCode;
}
```

and the conversion functions.

```
namespace UTF8Util
{
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTION: ConvertUTF8ToUTF16
// DESC: Converts Unicode UTF-8 text to Unicode UTF-16 (Windows default).
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CStringW ConvertUTF8ToUTF16( __in const CHAR * pszTextUTF8 )
{
    //
    // Special case of NULL or empty input string
    //
    if ( (pszTextUTF8 == NULL) || (*pszTextUTF8 == '\0') )
    {
        // Return empty string
        return L"";
    }

    //
    // Consider CHAR's count corresponding to total input string length,
    // including end-of-string (\0) character
    //
    const size_t cchUTF8Max = INT_MAX - 1;
    size_t cchUTF8;
    HRESULT hr = ::StringCchLengthA( pszTextUTF8, cchUTF8Max, &cchUTF8 );

    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        AtlThrow( hr );
    }

    // Consider also terminating \0
    ++cchUTF8;

    // Convert to 'int' for use with MultiByteToWideChar API
    int cbUTF8 = static_cast<int>( cchUTF8 );

    //
    // Get size of destination UTF-16 buffer, in WCHAR's
    //
    int cchUTF16 = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8,                // convert from UTF-8
        MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,   // error on invalid chars
        pszTextUTF8,            // source UTF-8 string
        cbUTF8,                 // total length of source UTF-8 string,
                                // in CHAR's (= bytes), including end-of-string \0
        NULL,                   // unused - no conversion done in this step
        0                       // request size of destination buffer, in WCHAR's
        );

    ATLASSERT( cchUTF16 != 0 );

    if ( cchUTF16 == 0 )
    {
        AtlThrowLastWin32();
    }

    //
    // Allocate destination buffer to store UTF-16 string
    //
    CStringW strUTF16;
    WCHAR * pszUTF16 = strUTF16.GetBuffer( cchUTF16 );

    //
    // Do the conversion from UTF-8 to UTF-16
    //

    int result = ::MultiByteToWideChar(
        CP_UTF8,                // convert from UTF-8
        MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,   // error on invalid chars
        pszTextUTF8,            // source UTF-8 string
        cbUTF8,                 // total length of source UTF-8 string,
                                // in CHAR's (= bytes), including end-of-string \0
        pszUTF16,               // destination buffer
        cchUTF16                // size of destination buffer, in WCHAR's
        );

    ATLASSERT( result != 0 );

    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        AtlThrowLastWin32();
    }

    // Release internal CString buffer
    strUTF16.ReleaseBuffer();

    // Return resulting UTF16 string
    return strUTF16;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTION: ConvertUTF16ToUTF8
// DESC: Converts Unicode UTF-16 (Windows default) text to Unicode UTF-8.
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CStringA ConvertUTF16ToUTF8( __in const WCHAR * pszTextUTF16 )
{
    //
    // Special case of NULL or empty input string
    //
    if ( (pszTextUTF16 == NULL) || (*pszTextUTF16 == L'\0') )
    {
        // Return empty string
        return "";
    }

    //
    // Consider WCHAR's count corresponding to total input string length,
    // including end-of-string (L'\0') character.
    //
    const size_t cchUTF16Max = INT_MAX - 1;
    size_t cchUTF16;
    HRESULT hr = ::StringCchLengthW( pszTextUTF16, cchUTF16Max, &cchUTF16 );

    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        AtlThrow( hr );
    }

    // Consider also terminating \0
    ++cchUTF16;

    //
    // WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS flag is set to fail if invalid input character
    // is encountered.
    // This flag is supported on Windows Vista and later.
    // Don't use it on Windows XP and previous.
    //

#if (WINVER >= 0x0600)
    DWORD dwConversionFlags = WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS;
#else
    DWORD dwConversionFlags = 0;
#endif

    //
    // Get size of destination UTF-8 buffer, in CHAR's (= bytes)
    //
    int cbUTF8 = ::WideCharToMultiByte(
        CP_UTF8,                // convert to UTF-8
        dwConversionFlags,      // specify conversion behavior
        pszTextUTF16,           // source UTF-16 string
        static_cast<int>( cchUTF16 ),   // total source string length, in WCHAR's,
                                        // including end-of-string \0
        NULL,                   // unused - no conversion required in this step
        0,                      // request buffer size
        NULL, NULL              // unused
        );

    ATLASSERT( cbUTF8 != 0 );

    if ( cbUTF8 == 0 )
    {
        AtlThrowLastWin32();
    }

    //
    // Allocate destination buffer for UTF-8 string
    //
    CStringA strUTF8;
    int cchUTF8 = cbUTF8; // sizeof(CHAR) = 1 byte
    CHAR * pszUTF8 = strUTF8.GetBuffer( cchUTF8 );

    //
    // Do the conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8
    //
    int result = ::WideCharToMultiByte(
        CP_UTF8,                // convert to UTF-8
        dwConversionFlags,      // specify conversion behavior
        pszTextUTF16,           // source UTF-16 string
        static_cast<int>( cchUTF16 ),   // total source string length, in WCHAR's,
                                        // including end-of-string \0
        pszUTF8,                // destination buffer
        cbUTF8,                 // destination buffer size, in bytes
        NULL, NULL              // unused
        ); 

    ATLASSERT( result != 0 );

    if ( result == 0 )
    {
        AtlThrowLastWin32();
    }

    // Release internal CString buffer
    strUTF8.ReleaseBuffer();

    // Return resulting UTF-8 string
    return strUTF8;
}

} // namespace UTF8Util
```

However, during runtime, I get the exception at

> ATLASSERT( cbUTF8 != 0 );

while trying to get size of destination UTF-8 buffer

1. What thing I had missed out?
2. If I am testing using a Chinese characters, How can I verify the resultant UTF-8 string is correct?

Comment: GetLastError? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful

Comment: could it be that _UNICODE is not enabled? Recommending to use WCHAR instead of TCHAR to eliminate dependency on this dangerous define.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you specified the `WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS` flag:

> **Windows Vista and later:** Fail if an invalid input character is encountered. If this flag is not set, the function silently drops illegal code points. A call to GetLastError returns ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION. Note that this flag only applies when CodePage  is specified as CP_UTF8 or 54936 (for Windows Vista and later). It cannot be used with other code page values.

Your conversion function seems quite long.  How does this one work for you?

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// FUNCTION: ConvertUTF16ToUTF8
// DESC: Converts Unicode UTF-16 (Windows default) text to Unicode UTF-8.
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CStringA ConvertUTF16ToUTF8( __in LPCWSTR pszTextUTF16 ) {
    if (pszTextUTF16 == NULL) return "";

    int utf16len = wcslen(pszTextUTF16);
    int utf8len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszTextUTF16, utf16len, 
        NULL, 0, NULL, NULL );

    CArray<CHAR> buffer;
    buffer.SetSize(utf8len+1);
    buffer.SetAt(utf8len, '\0');

    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszTextUTF16, utf16len, 
        buffer.GetData(), utf8len, 0, 0 );

    return buffer.GetData();
}
```

I see you use a function called `StringCchLengthW` to get the required length of the output buffer.  Most of the places I look recommend using the `WideCharToMultiByte` function itself to tell you how many CHARs it wants.

**Edit:**
As Rob pointed out, you can use CW2A with the CP_UTF8 code page:

```
CStringA str = CW2A(wStr, CP_UTF8);
```

While I'm editing, I can answer your second question:

> How can I verify the resultant UTF-8 string is correct?

Write it to a text file, then open it in Mozilla Firefox or an equivillant program. In the View menu, you can go to Character Encoding and switch manually to UTF-8 (assuming Firefox didn't guess it correctly to begin with).  Compare it with a UTF-16 document with the same text and see if there are any differences.

Comment: Thanks. But, don't you need to consider the null terminated \0 by int utf16len = wcslen(pszTextUTF16); ?

Comment: And I thought I shall decide on WC_ERR_INVALID_CHARS during compile time. It seems that it is not the case.

Comment: The utf16len variable is used to tell the function how many WCHARs to read.  It doesn't need to read the null terminator.

Comment: I usually use something more akin to this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5974ce99a19def2f.  Shorter, fewer copies of strings, and allows you to convert non-null-terminated strings.

Comment: Instead of creating an intermediate array of char, you can use the buffer from CStringA directly: 

`CStringA result;
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, pszTextUTF16, utf16len, result.GetBufferSetLength(utf8len), utf8len, 0, 0 );
result.ReleaseBuffer(utf8len);
return result;`

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the [ATL String Conversion Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) - to convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 use `CW2A` and pass `CP_UTF8` as the code page, e.g.:

```
CW2A utf8(buffer, CP_UTF8);
const char* data = utf8.m_psz;
```

Comment: +1 I knew about those macros but I didn't know you could give code pages as a second parameter.

Comment: Sorry. I don't want to use ATL. My code will be standard c++. (For the example I gave, I will turn them into using wstring and string instead of CString.

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: There's no standard C++ way to convert text encoding. You're going to use Windows API anyway. And you don't need to use all of ATL to use this macro.

Comment: C'mon, turning UTF-18 into UTF-8 is the most trivial encoding in the world. You can do that in 30 lines of code. Don't try it in 20, because that will break on surrogates.

Comment: @MSalters, any comments on my "20 lines of code" at http://stackoverflow.com/a/148766/5987?

Comment: It's closer to 30 lines, isn't it? You're testing twice for `>=U+10000`, both in the UTF-16 decode and the UTF-8 encode part. The early declaration of `codepoint` outside the loop is old C style, which causes a needless reset. Masking off the top bits (for the lead byte) isn't needed since the prior test of `codepoint` already proved they're zero. (like it's not done for the ASCII case)