# SQLite Unicode with Visual C++ 2015

Tags: sqlite, utf-8

This is my first SQLite + VC 2015 program, my project is in UTF-8.
I have SQLite table in which I want to save Chinese.
For example, I have table:

Cities {
  Id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  Desc TEXT }

Then, I have a dialog with a textfield, user input the City name there, and a CString variable m_szName link to it.

And, I have a piece code to insert the city into table:

```
stringstream sql;
sql << "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Cities "
    << " (Id,Desc) VALUES ('1001','" << m_szName.GetBuffer() << "')";
```

Now the problem is, m_szName.GetBuffer() returns TCHAR*, so above program has syntax error.
If I use "wstringstream sql", above code is good, but then it's not accepted by sqlite3_exec since it only accepts (char*).

I tried to convert TCHAR* to char* here and there, but nothing works.
Please help, thanks.

Comment: What is it that leads you to believe your VS project is in UTF-8?

Comment: I have option /utf-8 in my project properties \ C/C++ \ Command Line

Comment: That doesn't encode your program's strings to UTF-8. That just tells the compiler that your source files are in UTF-8. As @CL's answer points out, you must make certain that you pass the proper encoding to SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

`sqlite3_exec()` is one of the few functions that does not have a UTF-16 version, so you have to correctly [convert the string contents into UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082620/convert-utf-16-to-utf-8):

```cpp
CStringA str_utf8 = CW2A(m_szName.GetBuffer(), CP_UTF8);
```

However, your code will blow up when the name contains a quote. It would be a much better idea to use parameters, where it is also possible to use UTF-16 strings directly:

```cpp
const char *sql = "INSERT ... VALUES ('1001', ?)";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
    return;
}
sqlite3_bind_text16(stmt, 1, m_szName.GetBuffer(), -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
    cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
```

Comment: Hi CL, thanks for reply. I got a new issue when I try your way:

 sqlite3 * db;
 int rc = sqlite3_open("D:\\data.db3", &db);
 const char * sql =
  "INSERT INTO Account (Id,Name,Desc,Category,Type,Bookable,Hibernate) VALUES ('1001','Testing',?,'01','01',1,0)";
 rc = sqlite3_prepare16_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL);
 if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
  cerr << sqlite3_errmsg(db);
  return;
 }

It goes to sqlite3_errmsg and says: near "ä¹‰ä•“å‘’ä¤ å‘Žâ©â§ã¼¬âœ¬ã„°â°§ã€§âœ±ã„¬ã€¬": syntax error
My sql should be OK, it looks still encode problem, why it behave like this?

Comment: Sorry; the `sql` string is UTF-8 and should not have used `prepare16`.

Comment: Thanks a lot CL, it works. And actually your original reply is correct, I put prepare16 by mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: That is not the original answer …