# C++ equivalent of mbsrtowcs and wcsrtombs using locales and streams

Tags: c++, linux, internationalization, locale, libstdc++

Is there a C++ equivalent of mbsrtowcs and wcsrtombs type functions using std::locale and C++ streams functionality?

I'm trying to figure out the best way to convert back and forth between std::string and std::wstring using the standard library. It seems std::locale can almost do this, but I'm a little iffy on some details, or on what limitations it might have.

Some specifics: I'm on Linux, which uses utf-8 as the native encoding. I'd like to go from utf-8 std::string to std::wstring and back without losing information.

I think there may be some limitations with locales on Windows, but I'm not particularly concerned about them. As long as the answer works on Linux and has no dependencies beyond libstdc++ i.e. no boost dependency, I'm happy.

Links to background information appreciated.

NOTE: There seems to be some confusion. More than one char can represent a single character in UTF-8, so functions that do not account for this when converting from wchar_t to char will not work.

Answer (score 3):

`locale` is overkill for this task - UTF-8 and UTF-16 can be converted back and forth with simple binary conversions.  Here's some code, based on my [answer to an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl/148766#148766).

```
std::string UTF16to8(const wchar_t * in)
{
    std::string out;
    if (in == NULL)
        return out;

    unsigned int codepoint = 0;
    for (in;  *in != 0;  ++in)
    {
        if (*in >= 0xd800 && *in <= 0xdbff)
            codepoint = ((*in - 0xd800) << 10) + 0x10000;
        else
        {
            if (*in >= 0xdc00 && *in <= 0xdfff)
                codepoint |= *in - 0xdc00;
            else
                codepoint = *in;

            if (codepoint <= 0x7f)
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(codepoint));
            else if (codepoint <= 0x7ff)
            {
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xc0 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x1f)));
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
            }
            else if (codepoint <= 0xffff)
            {
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xe0 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x0f)));
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f)));
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
            }
            else
            {
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xf0 | ((codepoint >> 18) & 0x07)));
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3f)));
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f)));
                out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
            }
            codepoint = 0;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

std::wstring UTF8to16(const char * in)
{
    std::wstring out;
    if (in == NULL)
        return out;

    unsigned int codepoint = 0;
    int following = 0;
    for (in;  *in != 0;  ++in)
    {
        unsigned char ch = *in;
        if (ch <= 0x7f)
        {
            codepoint = ch;
            following = 0;
        }
        else if (ch <= 0xbf)
        {
            if (following > 0)
            {
                codepoint = (codepoint << 6) | (ch & 0x3f);
                --following;
            }
        }
        else if (ch <= 0xdf)
        {
            codepoint = ch & 0x1f;
            following = 1;
        }
        else if (ch <= 0xef)
        {
            codepoint = ch & 0x0f;
            following = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            codepoint = ch & 0x07;
            following = 3;
        }
        if (following == 0)
        {
            if (codepoint > 0xffff)
            {
                out.append(1, static_cast<wchar_t>(0xd800 + (codepoint >> 10)));
                out.append(1, static_cast<wchar_t>(0xdc00 + (codepoint & 0x03ff)));
            }
            else
                out.append(1, static_cast<wchar_t>(codepoint));
            codepoint = 0;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Here's a version (untested) to use if your wchar_t is 32 bits rather than 16 bits.

```
std::string UTF32to8(const wchar_t * in)
{
    assert(sizeof(wchar_t) >= 4);
    std::string out;
    if (in == NULL)
        return out;

    for (in;  *in != 0;  ++in)
    {
        unsigned int codepoint = *in;

        if (codepoint <= 0x7f)
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(codepoint));
        else if (codepoint <= 0x7ff)
        {
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xc0 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x1f)));
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
        }
        else if (codepoint <= 0xffff)
        {
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xe0 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x0f)));
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f)));
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
        }
        else
        {
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xf0 | ((codepoint >> 18) & 0x07)));
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3f)));
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f)));
            out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
        }
    }
    return out;
}

std::wstring UTF8to32(const char * in)
{
    assert(sizeof(wchar_t) >= 4);
    std::wstring out;
    if (in == NULL)
        return out;

    wchar_t codepoint = 0;
    int following = 0;
    for (in;  *in != 0;  ++in)
    {
        unsigned char ch = *in;
        if (ch <= 0x7f)
        {
            codepoint = ch;
            following = 0;
        }
        else if (ch <= 0xbf)
        {
            if (following > 0)
            {
                codepoint = (codepoint << 6) | (ch & 0x3f);
                --following;
            }
        }
        else if (ch <= 0xdf)
        {
            codepoint = ch & 0x1f;
            following = 1;
        }
        else if (ch <= 0xef)
        {
            codepoint = ch & 0x0f;
            following = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            codepoint = ch & 0x07;
            following = 3;
        }
        if (following == 0)
        {
            out.append(1, codepoint);
            codepoint = 0;
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: wstrings are not UTF-16 on Linux.

Comment: @caf, I didn't know that. UCS-32 is even easier though.

Comment: Note that correct UTF-8 decoders **must** reject invalid sequences (eg. overlong encodings like `C0 A0`) - this is mandatory because it has historically been possible to sneak malicious input in through non-canonical encodings.

Comment: @caf, very good point. But don't you think it makes more sense for sanitizing to be a separate step?

Comment: Well, now we're talking philosophy ;) - but I tend to disagree, because 1) the sanitizing requires implementing the same state machine as the decoding; and 2) that introduces the possibility of TOCTTOU bugs.

Comment: Whenever I see people posting their handmade UTF-8 conversion routines, violent feelings bubble up in me.

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried to create some simple function?

```
std::wstring StringToWString(const std::string& src)
{
 std::wstring str(src.length(),L' ');
 std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), str.begin());
 return str; 
}


std::string WStringToString(const std::wstring& src)
{
 std::string str(src.length(), ' ');
 std::copy(src.begin(), src.end(), str.begin());
 return str; 
}

void main()
{
 string s1 = "Hello World!";
 wstring s2 = StringToWString(s1);
 s1 = WStringToString(s2);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that WStringToString is correct. You are just converting wchar_t to char. This doesn't change the encoding, and should break on code points not representable by ascii.