# Convert UTF8 encoded byte buffer to wstring?

Tags: c++, stl, cross-platform

Does the C++ Standard Template Library (STL) provide any method to convert a UTF8 encoded byte buffer into a wstring?

For example:

```
const unsigned char* szBuf = (const unsigned char*) "d\xC3\xA9j\xC3\xA0 vu";
std::wstring str = method(szBuf); // Should assign "déjà vu" to str
```

I want to avoid having to implement my own UTF8 conversion code, like this:

```
const unsigned char* pch = szBuf;    
while (*pch != 0)
{
    if ((*pch & 0x80) == 0)
    {
    str += *pch++;
    }
    else if ((*pch & 0xE0) == 0xC0 && (pch[1] & 0xC0) == 0x80)
    {
        wchar_t ch = (((*pch & 0x1F) >> 2) << 8) +
            ((*pch & 0x03) << 6) +
            (pch[1] & 0x3F);
        str += ch;
        pch += 2;
    }
    else if (...)
    {
        // other cases omitted
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks for your comments and the answer. This code fragment performs the desired conversion:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>,wchar_t> convert;
str = convert.from_bytes((const char*)szBuf);
```

Comment: For C++11, yes! See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7235204/209199

Comment: With the new `codecvt` facilities, you can convert the UTF-8 to UTF-32, the wide to narrow, and the narrow to UTF-32, and then compare the two UTF-32 sequences.

Comment: if c++11 is not an option, you can see utf-cpp libray : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14603997/1497972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11 you can use [`std::codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8).  If you don't have that, you *may* be able to persuade [`iconv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/iconv.html) to do what you want; unfortunately, that's not ubiquitous either, not all implementations that have it support UTF-8, and I'm not aware of *any* way to find out the appropriate thing to pass to `iconv_open` to do a conversion from `wchar_t`.

If you don't have either of those things, your best bet is a third-party library such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).  Surprisingly, Boost does not appear to have anything to the purpose, although I coulda missed it.