# Convert between string, u16string & u32string using libstdc++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, c++11, unicode-string

I found this topic [Convert between string, u16string & u32string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232710/convert-between-string-u16string-u32string) and the solution (which looks really great) works only using libc++ not libstdc++. Currently libc++ is not usable - it is hard to compile and dont work good on Windows.

Is there any method to convert between these representations using C++11 and libstdc++, which works on all platforms?

I'm especially interested in converting u32_string to string (utf8) and vice versa.

Comment: Converting from a 32-bit Unicode string to utf8 is very simple, it's about 10 lines of code. Any reason you can't just write the code? utf8 to a 32-bit Unicode string is not hugely more difficult. These formats are simple and well documented.

Comment: I would love to use proven library and not mess with it myself. I didnt know it is so simple, but I'm sure somebody did it before, so I would love to use it - I really strongly belive in code reusability ;)

Comment: There's always [boost.locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: To make it easier to debug Unicode text issues (that inevitably any programmer working with text will encounter), it is most likely a good idea to learn the UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoding/decoding algorithms.  Once you have learned how Unicode works then you can reassess whether they are worth reusing or writing your own.  The C++ standard Unicode conversion functions are in `locale/codecvt`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way portable way in C++11 to do this through the [wstring_convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) class.

However, it seems that it is not yet implemented libstdc++ (as of gcc 4.8)

The same applies to:

```
codecvt<char16_t, char, mbstate_t>.
codecvt<char32_t, char, mbstate_t>.
codecvt_utf8.
codecvt_utf16.
codecvt_utf8_utf16.
```

In fact the header `<codecvt>` is still not present in the gcc distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use utf8cpp (http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) it provides those converters as easily useable C++.