# Is basic_string conversion via iterators legal?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, string-conversion

Is iterator a propper conversion between basic_strings? Is this safe/legal? Does this create a valid string?

```
std::u16string str16;
//str16 is set here;
std::string cStr(str16.cbegin(), str16.cend());
```

In VS 2013 it seem to work ok.

Comment: This will not convert your string to another encoding, just copy it element by element. If your str16 contains code units that do not fit into `char`, they will be truncated.

Comment: related, not exact duplicate:  [convert between string, u16string, u32string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232710/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is legal, because a `char` can be initialized from a `char16_t`. However, the result of the conversion is implementation-defined if the `char` is signed and the value is too large to fit (C++11 §4.7/3). (Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is also implementation-defined, §3.9.1/1.)

As pointed out in comments, this will not convert your string into another encoding. (That being said, it will probably work in the case that the string contains only ASCII characters. *That* being said, don't do it.)