# Convert a char16_t to long/integer, (atoi / atol equivalent)

Tags: c++11

I want to convert a char16_t to an integer and/or a long.

```
const char16_t* t = u"12";
long lt = atol( t);
```

Does such a function not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function: (it's not necessarily the most efficient solution, but it gets the job done if you have no choice (i.e. you have to have a `char16_t*` as input) **and** you're sure that you actually have a valid sequence of digits in your `char16_t*` string)

<kbd>[**Run It Online**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1f6c38e21016a3c)</kbd>

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int char16_to_int(const char16_t* s16)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235204/865719
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    std::string str = convert.to_bytes(s16);

    return std::stoi(str);
}

long char16_to_long(const char16_t* s16)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235204/865719
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    std::string str = convert.to_bytes(s16);

    return std::stol(str);
}
```

**EDIT**: I've refactored the solution just a little bit to reduce repetition:

<kbd>[**Run It Online**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6ed59d5abaeb89c)</kbd>

```
#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

std::string char16_to_string(const char16_t* s16)
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/7235204/865719
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    return convert.to_bytes(s16);
}

long char16_to_long(const char16_t* s16)
{
    return stol(char16_to_string(s16));
}

int char16_to_int(const char16_t* s16)
{
    return stoi(char16_to_string(s16));
}
```

Comment: great function(s), I will add try / catch blocks in case non numbers are passed.