# C++ wprintf format specifier for char16_t for printing unicode string

Tags: c++, printf

I have the following code successfully compiled:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    
    char16_t chinese[] = u"\u4e66\u4e2d\u81ea\u6709\u9ec4\u91d1\u5c4b";
    wprintf(L"String written with unicode codes: %ls \n", chinese);
    
    wchar_t arabic[] = L"أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة";
    wprintf(L"String written with L-String: %ls \n", arabic);
    std::wcout << std::endl;  std::system("PAUSE");
}
```

It prints:

- String written with unicode codes: 书中自有黄金屋
- String written with L-String: أَبْجَدِيَّة عَرَبِيَّة

However, the compiler issues a warning for chinese case (not for arabic case):

```
warning C4477: 'wprintf' : format string '%ls' requires an argument of type 'wchar_t *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'char16_t *'
```

What would be then the correct wprintf format string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wchar_t` is not the same as `char16_t`. `wchar_t` are 2 byte characters on windows, but (usually) 4 byte characters on linux. This is like the `int` vs. `int16_t` problem. The standard does not define `wchar_t`.

So the question is not what format specifier to use with wprintf. It's rather how to convert a `char16_t` string to a `wchar_t` string.

Under Windows you might get away with simply casting a `char16_t` to a `wchar_t`, which is what happens implicitly with `wprintf`, since it does not actually validate it's parameters. The warning `C4477` is just a little help by the (Visual Studio?) compiler hinting at your problem.

But on other platforms you have to actually convert the string.

So the best solution would be something like this:
`wprintf("%ls", boost::utf16_to_wchar_t(chinese));` (I am just throwing in boost here, since they have conversion functions. I don't know the exact function to use).

Or alternatively use `wchar_t` escape sequences and define your `chinese` as a `wchar_t*` string.

Comment: Visual Studio indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> What would be then the correct wprintf format string?

There is no `printf` format specifier for `char16_t`. It does not exist.

You have to convert your `char16_t` string to multibyte string or wide string and print it then.

`c16rtomb` would be the standard C function to do it. [Convert between string, u16string & u32string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232710/convert-between-string-u16string-u32string) shows how to do it in C++.