# How to convert char16_t to wchar_t to print out with wprintf

Tags: c++, type-conversion, wchar-t, codecvt, char16-t

I am trying to write a function to convert a  **const char16_***  to a **const wchar_t*** to use it in wprintf later on:

```
const wchar_t* wchart_from_char16(const char16_t*) {
   ???
}

int main(){
  const char16_t* my = u"The Text I want to print";
  const wchar_t* ret = wchart_from_char16(my);
  wprintf(L"The Text is is: %ls ", ret);
 }
```

**How can I do this using codecvt ?** This needs to work cross platform

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71218932/c-convert-wchar-t-to-char16-t-and-back  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232710/convert-between-string-u16string-u32string

Comment: Thanks KamilCouk, I tried to understand that but couldn`t. And I do not want to use UTF 8.

Comment: Is this under Windows?

Comment: I will suspect ` do not want to use UTF 8` and `can I do this using codecvt ?` are in  conflict. If you want to convert utf-16 to utf-32, use an external library like libunistring or icu. If you want to convert char16_t to wchar_t, you will have to convert to char16_t to multibyte string and then multibyte string to wchar_t (at least in C).

Comment: The cross-platform part will hit a real hurdle in that `wchar_t` has difference sizes on different platforms. That's probably why we have `char16_t` in the first place!