# c++ how to convert wchar_t to char16_t

Tags: c++, type-conversion, wchar-t, char16-t

[Convert between string, u16string & u32string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232710/convert-between-string-u16string-u32string)
This post explains the opposite of my question. So I need to post a new question

I need to convert wchar_t to char16_t. I found a sample of doing the opposite ( char16_t -> wchar_t) here:

I am not familiar with templates etc, sorry. **Can anybody give me an example of converting wchar_t to char16_t please?**

I have this piece of code that I want to adapt for converting wchar_t to char16_t.

```
 std::wstring u16fmt(const char16_t* str) {
 std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert_wstring;
 std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
 std::string utf8str = convert.to_bytes(str);
 std::wstring wstr = convert_wstring.from_bytes(utf8str);
 return wstr;
}
```

Ah, and it should run on Windows and Linux

Comment: How do you obtain the `wchar_t`? Does it already contain UTF-16 data?

Comment: It is not safe to do that as it might be 32-bit wide while `char16_t` is 16-bit for UTF-16

Comment: Do you want to convert *single chars*, or *strings*?

Answer (score 1):

If `sizeof( wchar_t ) == 2` (*), you're straddled with Windows and can only hope your `wstring` holds UTF-16 (and hasn't been smashed flat to UCS-2 by some old Windows function).

If `sizeof( wchar_t ) == 4` (*), you're not on Windows and need to do a UTF-32 to UTF-16 conversion.

(*): Assuming `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

I am, however, rather pessimistic about standard library's Unicode capabilities beyond simple "piping through", so if you're going to do any actual *work* on those strings, I'd recommend [ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/), the de-facto C/C++ standard library for all things Unicode.

`icu::UnicodeString` has a [`wchar_t *` constructor](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#ad207684eda109f23b5484a7a037e7327), and you can call [getTerminatedBuffer()](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#ac147028068f109ed48575b1be2585e1e) to get a (non-owning) `const char16_t *`. Or, of course, just use `icu::UnicodeString`, which uses UTF-16 internally.