# How to convert UTF-32 (hex) to UTF-8 (hex)

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring, type-conversion

In Obj-C, how to convert`\u20000`to this final string:`"%F0%A0%80%80"`(which will be used to build an URL)?

FYI: according to [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20000/index.htm),`\u20000`=`0x00020000`in UTF-32 (hex) or`0xF0 0xA0 0x80 0x80`in UTF-8 (hex).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using @ParagBafna's suggestion, which is using this code [ConvertUTF](http://www.koders.com/c/fid112E1609930ADAE7CA143040A834BAC0165DCD65.aspx?s=ConvertUTF.h), from [this link](http://www.koders.com/c/fid112E1609930ADAE7CA143040A834BAC0165DCD65.aspx?s=ConvertUTF.h). It works just fine.

Comment: So what's the solution? Link doesn't contain any info :/

Comment: Why down-vote my answer when the link is not under my responsibility? Why not simply ask the author of the code mentioned above, which is so easily available though a basic Google search: https://stackoverflow.com/users/944634/parag-bafna

Comment: Not to pile on, but the reason for the downvote is that your answer didn’t really provide a technical “answer” to OP question, you simply provided a link to something