# Unsigned integer as UTF-8 value

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, utf-8

assuming that I have

```
uint32_t a(3084);
```

I would like to create a string that stores the unicode character `U+3084` which means that I should take the value of `a` and use it as the coordinate for the right character in the UTF8 table/charset.

Now, clearly `std::to_string()` doesn't work for me, there are a lot of functions in the standard to convert between numeric values and char, I can't find anything that grants me UTF8 support and outputs an `std::string`.

I would like to ask if I have to create this function from scratch or there is something in the C++11 standard that can help me with that; please note that my compiler ( gcc/g++ 4.8.1 ) doesn't offer a complete support for `codecvt`.

Comment: Note, the integer 3084 would actually correspond to the character U+0C0C, since Unicode codepoint numbers are expressed in hexadecimal.

Comment: @Wyzard and that's just part of the problem, anyway I will be happy with `char` too instead of `std::string` as an output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some C++ code that wouldn't be hard to convert to C. Adapted from an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148766/5987).

```
std::string UnicodeToUTF8(unsigned int codepoint)
{
    std::string out;

    if (codepoint <= 0x7f)
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(codepoint));
    else if (codepoint <= 0x7ff)
    {
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xc0 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x1f)));
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
    }
    else if (codepoint <= 0xffff)
    {
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xe0 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x0f)));
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f)));
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
    }
    else
    {
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0xf0 | ((codepoint >> 18) & 0x07)));
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3f)));
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f)));
        out.append(1, static_cast<char>(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f)));
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: it's perfect just the way it is, I need this for C++ 11 non C, thanks.

Comment: @user2485710 the question was originally tagged C along with C++, that's why I mentioned it. I see you removed that tag.

Comment: Note that the 4-byte encoding of UTF-8 can only handle codepoints up to U+1FFFFF, but `unsigned int` can go up to 0xffffffff, so you might want to add a check for that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, if you're going to worry about invalid Unicode there's a lot more to worry about than an out-of-bounds codepoint. I'm a firm believer in Garbage In, Garbage Out. That said this code already strips off the upper bits if present.

Answer (score 8):

[std::string_convert::to_bytes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes) has a single-char overload just for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <iomanip>

// utility function for output
void hex_print(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for(unsigned char c : s)
        std::cout << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(c) << ' ';
    std::cout << std::dec << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t a(3084);

    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv1;
    std::string u8str = conv1.to_bytes(a);
    std::cout << "UTF-8 conversion produced " << u8str.size() << " bytes:\n";
    hex_print(u8str);
}
```

I get (with libc++)

```
$ ./test
UTF-8 conversion produced 3 bytes:
e0 b0 8c
```

Comment: This is the first example of `codecvt` I've ever seen work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard contains the `std::codecvt<char32_t, char, mbstate_t>` facet which converts between UTF-32 and UTF-8 according to 22.4.1.4 [locale.codecvt] paragraph 3. Sadly, the `std::codecvt<...>` facets aren't easy to use. At some point there was discussion about filtering stream buffers which would take case of the code conversion (the standard C++ library needs to implement them anyway for `std::basic_filebuf<...>`) but I can't see any trace of these.

Comment: there is nothing for just an `unsigned` to `char` conversion ? I have noticed that the UTF support is the part of the C++ standard that just floats randomly among different implementations, it's probably the only part that is "complex" to handle because is poorly implemented and poorly executed .

Comment: [std::wstring_convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes) isn't all that hard to use...

Comment: @Cubbi in theory yes, in practice, it's just not implemented yet for my compiler/standard library.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto s = u8"\343\202\204"; // Octal escaped representation of HIRAGANA LETTER YA
std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

prints

```
や
```

for me (using g++ 4.8.1). `s` has type `const char*`, as you'd expect, but I don't know if this is implementation defined. Unfortunately C++ doesn't have any support for manipulation of UTF8 strings are far as I know; for that you need to use a library like `Glib::ustring`.

Comment: thanks but this is the easier way, at compile time, I need this at runtime.