# Weird results when I iterate through string with "ñ" char

Tags: c++

I have a string of characters and one of those possible characters is the letter "ñ". My problem is, my string seems to behave in a weird way when I try to modify it or iterate through the string. For example if I have the code:

```
std::ifstream infile (argv[1]);
std::string texto_crudo((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(infile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
for (int i = 0; i<texto_crudo.length(); i++){
    if(es_enie(texto_crudo[i])) {
        texto_crudo[i] = '$';
    }
}
```

Where es_enie returns true if texto_crudo[i] = ñ. It seems like in the cell where ñ is located it behaves as if it has two values instead of one.

Comment: Perhaps because the text in the file happens to be [**UTF-8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded?

Comment: Im not familiar with UTF-8. The file I need to read is a .txt file. In case this is the problem, how could i solve this?

Comment: You have to replace substring `"ñ"` (of length 2) instead of individual char.

Comment: Why this question has a score of -1? To me, it seems to be genuine question.

Comment: With (custom) [ReplaceAll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29752943/2684539), it would be `ReplaceAll(texto_crudo, "ñ", "$");`

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find a solution to my exact problem. As Some programmer dude commented, it was because my text was in UTF-8 and I needed to convert it to iso-8859-1 in order to be able to use "ñ" correctly.
[Convert string from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689733/convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1)

Comment: Alternatively, you can fix `es_enie` so that it takes utf8 input. Characters are not necessarily 1 `char` long