# How to convert accented character to hex in C++?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

Referring to the ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) encoding:

[image]

The capital E acute (`É`) has a hex value of `C9`.

I am trying to write a function that takes a `std::string` and then converts it to hex according to the ISO-8859-1 encoding above.

Currently, I am only able to write a function that converts an ASCII string to hex:

```
std::string Helper::ToHex(std::string input) {
    std::stringstream strstream;
    std::string output;
    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++) {
        strstream << std::hex << unsigned(input[i]);
    }
    strstream >> output;
}
```

However, this function can't do the job when the input has accented characters. It will convert `É` to a hex value of `ffffffc3ffffff89`.

Comment: Please explain "this function can't do the job". What does it do?

Comment: @S.M. updated in the description, thanks

Comment: You have to cast it to `unsigned char`, not `unsigned`. (which would get you c389 because your string is not in iso-8859-1)

Comment: Your string is encoded as UTF-8. not ISO 8859-1. If you want ISO 8859-1 encoding, you need to re-encode it.

Comment: @dratenik, how do I encode my string to iso-8859-1?

Comment: There are libraries like iconv or ICU which you can use for such a conversion.

Comment: @dratenik since ISO-8859-1 is used for the first 256 code points of Unicode, there's no need for a full blown library.  A simple function that decodes UTF-8 to Unicode will do.  See e.g. [UTF8 to/from wide char conversion in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148403/5987).

Comment: @dratenik "*You have to cast it to `unsigned char`, not `unsigned`*" - actually, you need both.  `unsigned char` to avoid the sign extension issue, and `unsigned` so `std::hex` will take effect (because `operator<<` treats an `unsigned char` as text, not as an integer).

Comment: @MarkRansom "*since ISO-8859-1 is used for the first 256 code points of Unicode*" -  technically, ISO-8859-1 only covers 191 of the 1st 256 Unicode codepoints, there are gaps in the coverage. But of those 191, the bytes and codepoints are 1:1 in value, yes

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` has no encoding of its own.  It can easily hold characters encoded in ASCII, UTF-8, ISO-8859-x, Windows-125x, etc.  They are just raw bytes, as far as `std::string` is concerned. So, before you can print your output in ISO-8859-1 specifically, you need to first know what the `std::string` is already holding so it can be converted to ISO-8859-1 if needed.

FYI, `ffffffc3ffffff89` is simply the two `char` values `0xc3 0x89` (the UTF-8 encoded form of `É`) being sign-extended to 32 bits.  Which means your compiler implements `char` as a signed type rather than an `unsigned` type.  To eliminate the leading `f`s, you need to cast each `char` to `unsigned char` before then casting to `unsigned`.  You also will need to account for `unsigned` values < 10 so that the output is an even multiple of 2 hex digits per `char`, eg:

```cpp
strstream << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned>(static_cast<unsigned char>(input[i]));
```

So, it appears that your `std::string` is encoded in UTF-8.  There are plenty of libraries available that can convert text from one encoding to another, such as ICU or ICONV.  Or platform-specific APIs, like `WideCharToMultiByte()`/`MultiByteToWideChar()` on Windows, `std::mbstowcs()`/`std::wcstombs()`, etc (provided suitable locales are installed in the OS).  But there is nothing really built-in to C++ for this exact UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 conversion.  Though, you could use the (deprecated) `std::wstring_convert` to decode the UTF-8 `std::string` to a UTF-16/32 encoded `std::wstring`, or a UTF-16 encoded `std::u16string`, at least.  And then you can convert that to ISO-8859-1 using whatever library you want as needed.

Or, knowing that the input is UTF-8 and the output is ISO-8859-1, it is really not that hard to just convert the data manually, decoding the UTF-8 into codepoints, and then encoding those codepoints to bytes. Both encodings are well-documented and fairly easy to write code for without too much effort, eg:

```cpp
size_t nextUtf8CodepointLen(const char* data)
{
    unsigned char ch = static_cast<unsigned char>(*data);

    if ((ch & 0x80) == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if ((ch & 0xE0) == 0xC0) {
        return 2;
    }

    if ((ch & 0xF0) == 0xE0) {
        return 3;
    }

    if ((ch & 0xF8) == 0xF0) {
        return 4;
    }

   return 0;
}

unsigned nextUtf8Codepoint(const char* &data, size_t &data_size)
{
    if (data_size == 0) return -1;

    unsigned char ch = static_cast<unsigned char>(*data);
    size_t len = nextUtf8CodepointLen(data);

    ++data;
    --data_size;

    if (len < 2) {
        return (len == 1) ? static_cast<unsigned>(ch) : 0xFFFD;
    }

    --len;

    unsigned cp;

    if (len == 1) {
        cp = ch & 0x1F;
    }
    else if (len == 2) {
        cp = ch & 0x0F;
    }
    else {
        cp = ch & 0x07;
    }

    if (len > data_size) {
        data += data_size;
        data_size = 0;
        return 0xFFFD;
    }

    for(size_t j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
        ch = static_cast<unsigned char>(data[j]);

        if ((ch & 0xC0) != 0x80) {
            cp = 0xFFFD;
            break;
        }

        cp = (cp << 6) | (ch & 0x3F);
    }

    data += len;
    data_size -= len;

    return cp;
}

std::string Helper::ToHex(const std::string &input) {
    const char *data = input.c_str();
    size_t data_size = input.size();

    std::ostringstream oss;
    unsigned cp;

    while ((cp = nextUtf8Codepoint(data, data_size)) != -1) {
        if (cp > 0xFF) {
            cp = static_cast<unsigned>('?');
        }
        oss << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << cp;
    }

    return oss.str();
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/LnNPNU)

Comment: is there a way I can avoid using a library to conversion? Can I refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689733/convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1?

Comment: @zfgo I have updated my answer