# C++ UTF-8 to ISO-8859-2

Tags: c++

I have a problem with an application I'm building, multilingual.

I have 4 languages ​​​​(Portuguese, Spanish, English, Polish) and I would like to encode texts in 4 languages.

Note: I'm using lua for some scripts, this way, I'm intercepting the string, and converting the encoding depending on the language.

To convert the string to ISO-8859-1 I already managed using this guide -> [Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689733/convert-string-from-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1)

How would I convert it to ISO-8859-2?

I tried to use the same conversion, but  how the unicode change in the iso-8859-1 to iso-8859-2 code would be done

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: Latin-1 is easy because the Unicode encoding basically takes the codepoints from 128-255 and assigns them their Latin-1 meanings. So if you convert UTF-8 to a codepoint, you just store that number as the value for Latin-1 (if it is <256). Latin-2 requires more effort, an actual mapping from Unicode codepoints to the specific Latin-2 encodings.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to re-encode UTF-8 as this will by definition support all the languages you list?  LUA also supports basic UTF-8 handling.

Comment: https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/conversion/