# Windows UTF8 to UTF16

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8

I've been trying to convert between UTF8 and UTF16 LE with BOM using C++ to make the characters output correctly on Windows, without having to change the font of the terminal.

I tried changing the code pages, but they didn't work.

I have 2 questions,

1. How can I convert a normal string to a wide string?
2. Is it a bad idea to create a C++ map that maps each unicode character to the character in the Windows code page?

For example,

```
wcout << L"\u00A0" << endl;
```

This code outputs the letter `á` on Windows when using Code page 850. How can I put a variable in place of the `"\u00A0"` to convert a normal string to a wide character on Windows?

What I'd like is this:

```
wcout << Lsome_variable << endl;
```

I realise it's not valid c++ syntax but does anyone know how I can do this? Or if there's a better way?

Comment: There's [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert)

Comment: Just use wide strings all the way. And `_setmode` for the standard streams.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Better to use UTF-8 everywhere, except WINAPI calls forcing UTF-16. Wide is not Wide! [UTF-8 Everywhere Manifesto](http://www.utf8everywhere.org)

Comment: @Deduplicator: since visual c++, the main compiler on the windows platform, does not support utf-8 literals, and since the windows console subsystem does not support utf-8 input, it's just dumb to "use utf-8 everywhere". sorry. but that's how it is

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: If my comment is pure fanboy (which characterization I resent), yours is not any better. You neither link to nor provide any argument for going full-`wchar_t` being better in all and any circumstances. (I concede there are *specific cases* it is the easy way to go)

Comment: @Deduplicator: i think the fanboyness of your enthusiastic argument is well illustrated by your statement “You neither link to nor provide any argument for going full-wchar_t being better in all and any circumstances”, which (1) ignores the facts presented, and (2) misleadingly introduces a straw man to argue against. that's not an engineer's argument. it's a fanboy, or troll.

Comment: You want MultiByteToWideChar and WideCharToMutiByte functions. Since source code is interpreted as the local system language, avoid using anything but 7-bit ASCII in string literals. You can make UTF-16 string literals and use \x8a05 for other characters.

Comment: Alf: all this was said, and these concerns were answered in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful long time ago. The view you advocate here is, in fact, leading to more confusion. If you are not convinced, I would be happy if you post to that thread.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the one time it's almost mandatory to use UTF-8 is when you're trying to use `std::exception` with Unicode.  There are no methods that take or provide `wchar_t`.

Comment: See [UTF8 to/from wide char conversion in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148403/5987) for alternatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the standard library now provides things like [std::wstring_convert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) (and other functions/classes in the See Also section of that page).

Since you're on Windows, the WinAPI also has conversion functions. In this case you would be looking for [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can be used to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16.

Between those options, something should fit your use case. Generally speaking, you should never need to write your own conversion map.

Comment: A UTF to local character set conversion can also include character transforms that are not reversible, but visually resemble the original.

Comment: wstring_convert is deprecated now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946335/deprecated-header-codecvt-replacement