# Deprecated header <codecvt> replacement

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++17, utf-16, codecvt

A bit of foreground: my task required converting UTF-8 XML file to UTF-16 (with proper header, of course). And so I searched about usual ways of converting UTF-8 to UTF-16, and found out that one should use templates from `<codecvt>`.

But now when it is [deprecated](https://twitter.com/StephanTLavavej/status/837822661094846465), I wonder what is the new common way of doing the same task?

(Don't mind using Boost at all, but other than that I prefer to stay as close to standard library as possible.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`std::codecvt` template from `<locale>` itself isn't deprecated. For UTF-8 to UTF-16, there is still `std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>` specialization.

However, since `std::wstring_convert` and `std::wbuffer_convert` are deprecated along with the standard conversion facets, there isn't any easy way to convert strings using the facets.

So, as Bolas already answered: Implement it yourself (or you can use a third party library, as always) or keep using the deprecated API.

Comment: But according to [P0618](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html), *all* of the <codecvt> header is deprecated. Not just the typedefs; `std::codecvt` is deprecated in its entirety.

Comment: @NicolBolas The proposal appears to not suggest any changes to `[locale.codecvt]` where codecvt_base and codecvt of the `<locale>` header are defined. However, reading the document, I can see that w{string,buffer}_convert are deprecated as well, which as far as I know are the only standard function that actually uses the codecvt facet. So, even if codecvt isn't deprecated, there isn't really any easy way to use them. Do you think that the omission of `std::codecvt` form the document is accidental?

Comment: @user2079303 `basic_filebuf` uses it.

Comment: [P0618](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html) is just a proposal from one member of the standards committee, albeit an influential one.  It says nothing about whether the proposal has been accepted; if it has been, it won't be deprecated until the next standard (probably in the mid-2020s) and likely won't be removed until about 2030.  I imagine compilers will continue to support it for a while longer.

Comment: @RichardSmith according to [P0636R0](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html), P0618R0 was applied to C++17, which means that the depreciations are in effect since that standard revision.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `wX_convert` tools are deprecated because they relied on the deprecated specialisations of `std::codecvt`, rather than the other way around.  As such, if you are already using those specialisations, it _probably_ wouldn't cause any issues to use the converters along with them.

Comment: Recommend using this package: https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp

Answer (score 30):

**Don't worry about that.**

According to [the same information source](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0618r0.html):

> this library component should be retired to Annex D, along side ,
>   **until a suitable replacement is standardized**.

So, you can still use it until a new standardized, more-secure version is done.

Comment: Unfortunately, that was wishful thinking. Deprecation [was applied to C++17](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0636r0.html). The recommendation apparently is: *"Users should use dedicated text-processing libraries instead."* Visual Studio 2017 will issue deprecation warnings when used.

Comment: What dedicated text-processing library though?

Comment: Let's hope so since it is a bit too easy to just deprecate something without coming with an alternative.

Comment: What good are "standards" if they are changed on a whim without giving a suitable replacement? Maybe the "standards" are not so standard after all. Don't the "standards" committees take into account the man hours wasted as a result of deprecation without suitable replacement?

Comment: @camccar ICU : https://icu.unicode.org/

Comment: Recommend using this package: https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp

Comment: It seems this facility is now slated for removal in C++26 (see https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2872r2.pdf). What's the C++26 replacement?

Answer (score 17):

Since nobody really answers the question and provides usable replacement code, here is one but it's only for Windows:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <Windows.h>

std::wstring string_to_wide_string(const std::string& string)
{
    if (string.empty())
    {
        return L"";
    }

    const auto size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, string.data(), (int)string.size(), nullptr, 0);
    if (size_needed <= 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("MultiByteToWideChar() failed: " + std::to_string(size_needed));
    }

    std::wstring result(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, string.data(), (int)string.size(), result.data(), size_needed);
    return result;
}

std::string wide_string_to_string(const std::wstring& wide_string)
{
    if (wide_string.empty())
    {
        return "";
    }

    const auto size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wide_string.data(), (int)wide_string.size(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
    if (size_needed <= 0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("WideCharToMultiByte() failed: " + std::to_string(size_needed));
    }

    std::string result(size_needed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, wide_string.data(), (int)wide_string.size(), result.data(), size_needed, nullptr, nullptr);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: why not using `string.data()` instread of `&string.at(0)` as the input argument

Comment: @xenophōn: I agree with you, `.data()` is better

Answer (score 10):

The new way is... you write it yourself. Or just rely on deprecated functionality. Hopefully, the standards committee won't actually *remove* codecvt until there is a functioning replacement.

But at present, there isn't one.

Comment: It's the problem: I need the most portable way of doing this. Of course there are always things like icu, iconv and various other libs, but there was a fairly straight-forward way before, which involved three lines of code, and now it's a pure mess.

Comment: @login_not_failed not "was", it still is, since it's not removed (and not going to be removed for a while)

Comment: Written C++ for a long time, then try Rust, then comeback to work on some C++ projects; I admitted that Rust is a lot better. I don't understand why they deprecated this functionality without providing a replacement.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon: Deprecation does not mean *removal*. You're *supposed* to deprecate bad APIs that you intend to replace, even if you don't have a replacement right now. That's what deprecation is *for*.

Comment: https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp

Comment: Is it really that hard for the standards committee to implement a replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Well Options is what you need so yes you CAN use it still. I ifdef it. Some places its ok and others your not allowed to use it. Still need to convert though right ?

```
#ifdef _CODECVT_  /// deprected in c++ 17
_STL_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_WARNING
    _NODISCARD std::optional<std::wstring> StrA2W(const std::string& Data)
{
    assert(Data.length() > 0);
    if (Data.length() == 0) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    using convert_typeX = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;
    return converterX.from_bytes(Data);
}

_NODISCARD std::optional<std::string>  StrW2A(const std::wstring& Data)
{
    assert(Data.length() > 0);
    if (Data.length() == 0) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    using convert_typeX = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;
    return converterX.to_bytes(Data);
}
_STL_RESTORE_DEPRECATED_WARNING
```

#else  // #ifdef *CODECVT*  /// deprecated in c++ 17

```
_NODISCARD std::optional<std::string> StrW2A(const std::wstring& Data) { // convert from LPWSTR to LPSTR
    assert(Data.length() > 0);
    if (Data.length() == 0) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    UINT acp = GetACP();
    int buflen = WideCharToMultiByte(acp, 0, Data.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr) + 8;
    auto dest = std::make_unique<char[]>(buflen);
    int buflen2 = WideCharToMultiByte(acp, 0, Data.c_str(), -1, dest.get(), buflen, NULL, NULL) + 8;
    assert(buflen == buflen2);
    if( buflen == buflen2) 
        return dest.get();
    return std::nullopt;
}

_NODISCARD std::optional<std::wstring> StrA2W(const std::string& Data) { // convert from LPSTR to LPWSTR
    assert(Data.length() > 0);
    if (Data.length() == 0) {
        return std::nullopt;
    }
    UINT acp = GetACP();
    auto buflen = MultiByteToWideChar(acp, 0, Data.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0) + 8;
    auto dest = std::make_unique<wchar_t[]>(buflen);
    auto buflen2 = (MultiByteToWideChar(acp, 0, Data.c_str(), -1, dest.get(), buflen) + 8);
    assert(buflen == buflen2);
    if (buflen == buflen2)
        return dest.get();
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

#endif // #ifdef *CODECVT*  /// deprected in c++ 17

If you include the header you use it otherwise the other functions are used instead. Transparently no other change required.

Comment: `WideCharToMultiByte` convert char array from pointer and count, it not necessary to pass `c_str()` and `-1` to it, also not necessary to add extra number like `8` (why is 8?), also a `std::string` may be constructed from pointer and count.
`int cch = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, Data.data(), Data.size(), nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);`
`auto dest = std::make_unique<char[]>(cch);`
`int res = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, Data.data(), Data.size(), dest.get(), cch, NULL, NULL);`
`if (cch == res)`
`return std::string(dest.get(), cch);`
`return std::nullopt;`