# Unicode conversion in C++17

Tags: string, unicode, c++17

C++11 introduced [ways to perform conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) between raw byte-strings, represented by `std::string`, and unicode strings, like `std::u32string`.

However, looking at [the page on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale), I see that the whole thing gets deprecated in C++17 (namely, [`std::wstring_convert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) and everything from the [`<codecvt>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/codecvt) header).

My attempts at finding a C++17-way to do the conversion failed: there seems to be no replacement, just deprecation of functionality.

*So, my question is*: **what is the correct standard way to perform the aforementioned conversion in C++17, and does it exist at all?**

Comment: wstring_convert is correct and standard. It was deprecated out of wishful thinking, like strstream

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946335

Comment: Deprecated does not mean "not available". It means "to eventually be removed". So using it remains valid, and it will be valid until there is a replacement

Comment: @Cubbi: "*It was deprecated out of wishful thinking, like strstream*" Both this stuff and `strstream` are on the chopping block, since replacements for them have been proposed (`strstream` being replaced by a `span<char>`-based stream). So it's hardly "wishful thinking".

Comment: @NicolBolas sure, p407+p408+p448. So in 2020, there's a chance that the promised replacement to something deprecated in 1998 might arrive. Here's hoping for new Unicode conversions by 2035.

Comment: @Cubbi: Or, it could be in 2020. Or did you miss [P0244](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/p0244r2.html)?