# How to convert wstring to const char* in C++17?

Tags: c++, string, windows, c++17, wstring

I'm trying to avoid using boost, .begin() and .end(), and codecvt since it's been deprecated. Is there any other good practice in converting wstring to const char * or even std::string in C++17 on Windows? Thanks!

Comment: You can't convert a string to `const char*`. A `const char*` can at best point to a string. Maybe you meant convert to `char[]`.

Comment: Other useful reading: [Deprecated header <codecvt> replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946335/deprecated-header-codecvt-replacement)