# Is there a replacement for wstring_convert in a recent standard?

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, c++17

In my current code (which is based on C++11) I use the following:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void Test(); 
private:
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > m_myconv
};

void Foo::Test()
{
    std::wstring temp = m_myconv.from_bytes( (const char *) charArray );
}
```

I'm converting the results of the SQLite library to the `std::wstring`.

I understand that with C++17, such conversion is deprecated and I will no longer be able to use this code.

Is there an alternative that I can use for all 3 major platforms: Windows, *nix and Mac?

I understand that there is a possibility of using Boost. But this is a last resort, i.e. if there is no solution with the standard library.

Comment: "*such conversion is deprecated and I will no longer be able to use this code.*" That's not what "deprecated" means. It means that the functionality can be removed under later standards, but that doesn't mean it isn't still there.

Comment: Look at the second answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43153057/6752050

Comment: @S.M., did you look at the very first comment for it?

Comment: @NicolBolas, and I want to be prepared when it will be removed.

Comment: @S.M., and that accepted answer is confusing, especially since there is a second one.

Comment: @Igor: "*I want to be prepared when it will be removed.*" When it is removed, you will know because it will only happen when C++ has real Unicode support.