# Non-latin input with wcin produces character '/0'

Tags: c++, cin, wchar-t

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

constexpr int SIZE=20;

int main()
{
    wchar_t input[SIZE+1];
    std::wcin >> input;

    input[SIZE] = '\0';
    
    wchar_t c;
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; ++i)
    {
        c=input[i];
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << std::hex << +c << ' ';
    }
}
```

With this code, if I enter any non-latin characters I can see 0's in their position.
For example, if I enter ФФFF, I get

```
   0    0   46   46    0   40    0    0    8    0    0    0    c    0    0    0 13a0   d1    0    0
```

I'm running Windows 10, using VSC and C++11 as a compiler, and I use [unicode hex character set](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html) (Cyrillic letters).
If I hardcode the characters and bypass wcin, I get

```
  424  424   46   46    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: This strongly depends on 1) your operating system 2) environment settings such as region and code page 3) the actual bytes you are passing. Please edit your question with all three so we can help you debug this.

Comment: Edited, provided all needed info. At least I think so.

Comment: Still missing 2 and 3. There are numerous ways to represent those characters, but we need to know which encoding your operating system expects and what encoding you are sending. We can deduce the latter from the exact *bytes* you are sending, the former is something you need to look up.

Comment: Uh, I don't really understand, how do I check that?

Comment: Show us the result of calling the [`chcp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) command. For the other question, enter the same string into a command like `copy con blah.txt` and tell us what bytes end up in blah.txt.

Comment: chcp:
`Active code page: 65001`;
blah.txt:
  FF

Comment: check the bytes with a hex editor. Need to know what bytes correspond to Ф.

Comment: There was no Ф in the blah, so showed up as 00 00. Ф's themselves show as D0 A4

Comment: Okay. That means your OS/console is set up for UTF-8 and your input is also encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: Unfortunately getting UTF-8 working with wcin is [a bit of a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48180107/1548468)

Comment: Just tried that piece of code, entered the same string (ФФFF), got ` $F F`

Comment: UPD: It actually works. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an answer, so I can flag it as a solution and flag this question as solved?

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer on that question is different, and copy pasting the answer seems wrong to me.