# Printing Latin characters in Linux terminal using `std::wstring` and `std::wcout`

Tags: c++, character-encoding, wchar-t

I'm coding in C++ on Linux (Ubuntu) and trying to print a string that contains some Latin characters.

Trying to debug, I have something like the following:

```cpp
std::wstring foo = L"ÆØÅ";
std::wcout << foo;
for(int i = 0; i < foo.length(); ++i) {
    std::wcout << std::hex << (int)foo[i] << " ";
    std::wcout << (char)foo[i];
}
```

Characteristics of output I get:

- The first print shows: `???`
- The loop prints the hex for the three characters as `c6 d8 c5`
- When `foo[i]` is cast to `char` (or `wchar_t`), nothing is printed

Environmental variable `$LANG` is set to default `en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: What part is it that you have a question about?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402918/10247460) may shed some light on your problem

Comment: @ Ted Lyngmo   The latin characters aren't properly printing to the console.  They print as ? or are not printed at all.

Comment: The name of your variable is misleading, even though it's named `u8` it is *not* UTF-8.  Casting those individual characters will not give you anything valid, you must do a full conversion.

Comment: @ Jorengarenar  A long article.  But it shows the const char[] as printing correctly.  But when I typecast to (char), nothing is printed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/148403/5987 may help.

Comment: Since you have *something* printed, I guess you are using `libstdc++`. It is possible to make it work if you set the locale properly. However `libc++` won't output any `wchar_t` that is not an ASCII character and I'm not aware of any plans to fix that. `wchar_t` is basically a dead end. Don't touch it with a six foot pole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the conclusion of the [answer I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402918/10247460) (which I still recommend reading) we can find:

> **When I should use `std::wstring` over `std::string`?**
>
> On Linux? Almost never, unless you use a toolkit/framework.

#### Short explanation why:

First of all, Linux is natively encoded in UTF-8 and is consequent in it (in contrast to e.g. Windows where files has one encoding and `cmd.exe` another).

Now let's have a look at such simple program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string  foo =  "ψA"; // character 'A' is just control sample
    std::wstring bar = L"ψA"; // --

    for (int i = 0; i < foo.length(); ++i) {
        std::cout  << static_cast<int>(foo[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < bar.length(); ++i) {
        std::wcout << static_cast<int>(bar[i]) << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
-49 -120 65 
968 65
```

What does it tell us? `65` is ASCII code of character 'A', it means that that `-49 -120` and `968` corresponds to 'ψ'.

In case of `char` character 'ψ' takes actually two `char`s. In case of `wchar_t` it's just one `wchar_t`.

Let's also check sizes of those types:

```cpp
std::cout << "sizeof(char)    : " << sizeof(char)    << std::endl;
std::cout << "sizeof(wchar_t) : " << sizeof(wchar_t) << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
sizeof(char)    : 1
sizeof(wchar_t) : 4
```

1 byte on my machine has standard 8 bits. `char` has 1 byte (8 bits), while `wchar_t` has 4 bytes (32 bits).

UTF-8 operates on, nomen omen, code units having 8 bits. There is is a fixed-length UTF-32 encoding used to encode Unicode code points that uses exactly 32 bits (4 bytes) per code point, but it's UTF-8 which Linux uses.

Ergo, **terminal expects to get those two negatively signed values to print character 'ψ', not one value which is way above ASCII table** (codes are defined up to number 127 - half of `char` possible values).

That's why `std::cout << char(-49) << char(-120);` will also print `ψ`.

---

> But it shows the const char[] as printing correctly. But when I typecast to (char), nothing is printed.

The character was already encoded different, there are different values in there, simple casting won't be enough to convert them.

And as I've shown, size `char` is 1 byte and of `wchar_t` is 4 bytes. You can safely cast upward, not downward.