# Numeric value of literal UTF-8 characters

Tags: c, string, unicode

I'm working on a string unescaping function that converts literal sequences like `\uxxxx` (where `xxxx` is a hex value) into bytes of corresponding value. I am planning to have the function get he first two characters of the `xxxx` sequence, calculate the byte value, and to the same with the second sequence.

But I ran into an unexpected result with literal typed UTF-8 characters. The following illustrates my issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char *str1 = "abcĢ";
    unsigned char *str2 = "abc\x01\x22";
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf ("String 1 character #%u: %x\n", i, str1[i]);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf ("String 2 character #%u: %x\n", i, str2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
String 1 character #0: 61
String 1 character #1: 62
String 1 character #2: 63
String 1 character #3: c4
String 1 character #4: a2
String 2 character #0: 61
String 2 character #1: 62
String 2 character #2: 63
String 2 character #3: 1
String 2 character #4: 22
```

Unicode character `Ģ` has e hex value of `\x0122`, so I would expect bytes #3 and #4 to be `\x01` and`x22` respectively.

Where do `c4` and `a2` come from? I guess I am not understanding how multi-byte characters in strings are encoded in C. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `c4`,`a2` is UTF-8 byte sequence for  `Ģ` (U+0122)  _Latin Capital Letter G With Cedilla_

Comment: Then my question is, what is the logic to convert `c4` `a2` into `0122` and back?

Comment: And, of course, if someone knows of a ready-made function that converts a literal `"\\u0122"` into `"\u0122"` that would resolve my problem very nicely... Not trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: UTF8 is not only the ordinal of the character, it also encodes the number of bytes that is needed to represent this character.

Comment: Your compiler might support `"\u0122"` as a 4-digit Unicode escape sequence; doubling up the backslash is not productive unless your compiler doesn't support the Unicode escape sequences, but if it doesn't support them, using the notation doesn't help.  For a start byte in the range 0xC2..0xDF (a 2-byte UTF8 character), you need `codepoint = ((utf8[0] & 0x1F) << 6) + (utf8[1] & 0x3F);`.  That assumes that `utf8[1]` is in the range 0x80..0xBF.

Comment: I guess that the conversion is not trivial but this snippet uncovers the logic: https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/52eda3e5677b4b03524e40c9f0ab1da5

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am not in control of the double backslash. It comes from user input containing characters with a specific escape sequence that I have to convert to C-native.

Comment: OK; then you'll need to write code that demands a backslash, a lower-case U, and 4 hex-digits (either case), and you'll need to convert the 4 hex digits into a 16-bit unsigned integer, or some larger type (32-bit `int`, optionally `unsigned`).  Not all that hard. Note that there must be 4 hex digits; it is a hard requirement; three or fewer is an invalid sequence with no unambiguous interpretation (error). Extra hex digits are irrelevant; they're outside the scope of the `\u` escape sequence (but must not be converted; so `strtol()` is not usable unless you extract the 4 digits into a string).

Comment: Note when using non-ASCII characters in a `char` string, the bytes that end up in the string depends on the encoding used for the source file.  In this case, your source file must be saved in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: So you want to convert a user input sequence containing a mixture of UTF-8 and C style backslash escape sequences into a UTF-8 output sequence?

Comment: @IanAbbott The input is a file handle. I would encounter custom escape sequences representing UC code points as the one in my other comment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding

Comment: Here's some code to convert Unicode code points to UTF-8: https://stackoverflow.com/a/148766/5987.  It's in C++ but wouldn't be hard to convert, especially if you're going one character at a time.

Comment: [UTF-8 to UTF-16 one-way conversion, written in C](https://gist.github.com/tommai78101/3631ed1f136b78238e85582f08bdc618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 can't work in a simplistic way of breaking a large value into individual bytes, because it would be ambiguous.  How would you tell the difference between [`"\u4142" (䅂)`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+4142) and the two character string `"AB"`?

The rules for producing a UTF-8 byte string from a Unicode code point number are quite simple, and eliminate the ambiguity.  Given any sequence of byte values, it either defines unambiguous codepoints or it's an invalid sequence.

Here's a simple function that will convert a single Unicode codepoint value to a UTF-8 byte sequence.

```
void codepoint_to_UTF8(int codepoint, char * out)
/* out must point to a buffer of at least 5 chars. */
{
    if (codepoint <= 0x7f)
        *out++ = (char)codepoint;
    else if (codepoint <= 0x7ff)
    {
        *out++ = (char)(0xc0 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x1f));
        *out++ = (char)(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f));
    }
    else if (codepoint <= 0xffff)
    {
        *out++ = (char)(0xe0 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x0f));
        *out++ = (char)(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f));
        *out++ = (char)(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f));
    }
    else
    {
        *out++ = (char)(0xf0 | ((codepoint >> 18) & 0x07));
        *out++ = (char)(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 12) & 0x3f));
        *out++ = (char)(0x80 | ((codepoint >> 6) & 0x3f));
        *out++ = (char)(0x80 | (codepoint & 0x3f));
    }
    *out = 0;
}
```

Note that this function does no error checking, so if you give it an input outside the valid Unicode range of 0 to 0x10ffff it will generate an incorrect (but still valid) UTF-8 sequence.

Answer (score 3):

> Unicode character `Ģ` has e hex value of `\x0122`, so I would expect bytes #3 and #4 to be `\x01` and `\x22` respectively.
>
> Where do `c4` and `a2` come from?

In Unicode, `Ģ` is codepoint `U+0122 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER G WITH CEDILLA`, which in UTF-8 is encoded as bytes `0xC4 0xA2`.

Either your source file is saved as UTF-8, or your compiler is configured to save string literals in UTF-8.  Either way, in your `str1` string, the literal `Ģ` is stored as UTF-8.  Thus:

```cpp
unsigned char *str1 = "abcĢ";
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```cpp
unsigned char literal[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0xC4, 0xA2, '\0'};
unsigned char *str1 = &literal[0];
```

In an escape sequence, the *entire sequence* represents a *single* numeric value. So, `\x01` and `\x22` represent the individual numeric values `0x01` hex (`1` decimal) and `0x22` hex (`34` decimal), respectively.  Thus:

```cpp
unsigned char *str2 = "abc\x01\x22";
```

is roughly equivalent to this:

```cpp
unsigned char literal[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0x01, 0x22, '\0'};
unsigned char *str2 = &literal[0];
```

You are simply outputting the raw bytes of the strings that `str1` and `str2` are pointing at.

The escape sequence `\u0122` represents the numeric value `0x0122` hex (`290` decimal), which in Unicode is codepoint `U+0122`, hence `C4 A2` in UTF-8.  So, if you have an input string like this:

```
const char *str = "abc\\u0122"; // {'a', 'b', 'c', '\', 'u', '0', '1', '2', '2', '\0'}
```

And you want to decode it to UTF-8, you would need to detect the `"\u"` prefix, extract the following `"0122"` substring, parse it as a hex number into an integer, interpret that integer as a Unicode codepoint, and convert it to UTF-8 (`a`, `b`, and `c` are already valid chars as-is in UTF-8).