# Conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'const _Elem', possible loss of data

Tags: c++

```cpp
TCHAR buf[MAX_PATH];
int aFolder = CSIDL_APPDATA;
if (SHGetFolderPath(NULL, aFolder, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, buf) != S_OK)
    *buf = '\0';

// buf     wchar_t
std::wstring str(&buf[0]); //convert to wstring
std::string str2(str.begin(), str.end()); //and convert to string.

std::string str3 = "\\settings.ini";
auto dir = str2 + str3;
```

warning:

```cpp
conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'const _Elem', possible loss of data
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char
1>          ]
```

What other way can I do this conversion without `"possible loss of data"`?
I have also tried to use `SHGetFolderPathW()` but it returns the same warning.

Comment: That's not how any of this works, you would just get a "string" that barely makes sense. Use `SHGetFolderPathA` instead to pull the ANSI version right away.

Comment: [WideCharToMultibyte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte)

Comment: You should also note that `ShGetFolderPath` is deprecated and its use is discouraged. Use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::wstring` is usually either UTF-16 or UTF-32. `std::string` is usually UTF-8. What you are doing is not a proper way of converting between those encodings. See [UTF8 to/from wide char conversion in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/148403/10147399)