# Scary warnings in ancient code converting wstring to string

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

An old method contains code like the following (anonymised):

```
        std::wstring wstr = ...;
        std::string str(wstr.begin(), wstr.end());
```

Previously this all compiled without warnings but as we update to C++17 and VS2019 (v142) and tidy project settings, it now gives these big scary warnings:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstring(2468,23): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'const _Elem', possible loss of data
        with
        [
            _Elem=char
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstring(2479): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::_Construct<wchar_t*>(_Iter,const _Iter,std::input_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Iter=wchar_t *
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstring(2479): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::_Construct<wchar_t*>(_Iter,const _Iter,std::input_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Iter=wchar_t *
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstring(2459): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::_Construct<wchar_t*>(const _Iter,const _Iter,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Iter=wchar_t *
        ]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xstring(2459): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::_Construct<wchar_t*>(const _Iter,const _Iter,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Iter=wchar_t *
        ]

message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>,0>(_Iter,_Iter,const _Alloc &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Elem=wchar_t,
            _Iter=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t>>>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
        ]
message : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>,0>(_Iter,_Iter,const _Alloc &)' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Elem=wchar_t,
            _Iter=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<wchar_t>>>,
            _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
        ]
```

I am pretty sure this code pre-dates use of UNICODE in our codebase - it *seems* to work but I don't really understand the warnings or what I should do about it.

I found this question: [UTF8 to/from wide char conversion in STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148403/utf8-to-from-wide-char-conversion-in-stl) but the nice neat solution has comments saying it's deprecated in C++17! It's somewhat a mystery why this code mixes string and wstring in the first place, is there an easy solution? Or is this a case "just leave it if it works?!"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry I was writing a different question and forgot I hadn't changed the title. Replaced it now, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: A `wstring` holds a `wchar_t` array.  `wchar_t` is wider than `char`, and "supports" characters that `char` doesn't.  The warnings are the compilers way of telling you that.

Comment: Event without warnings this code can work for ASCII characters only. Any none ASCII character will lead to strange errors and text distortions.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea when/which settings lead to this warning - I checked our build logs and I don't see it before I started updating things. I assume either the C++ or platform library version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are converting from a 16 bit string to an 8 bit string. Since 16 bits hold more data than 8, data will then get lost. If you are converting between UTF-16 and UTF-8, you need to do it properly with a conversion library.

C++ does provide conversion library in the form of: [codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/codecvt) (Deprecated in C++17 but still there for a while).

If you are sure the string only contains ASCII, you can suppress the warning.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16 for details

Comment: It should be noted that `<codecvt>` is was deprecated in C++17 and may one day be removed from the language.

Comment: Ah it's only deprecated not removed? In that case the solution in my linked question may be valid at least for now

Comment: Note that `wchar_t` (and thus, the elements of a `std::wstring`) can be wider than 16 bits, and often are (Linux has 32 bits). Windows seems the only common platform where it is still 16 bits.

Comment: @Mr.Boy As of C++20, and the C++23 draft, it's still in the language.  You just not guarantee moving forward from there that it will still exist, although I think it will for some time since there is bounds to be lots of code using it.

Comment: The 200lb Gorilla for unicode is http://site.icu-project.org/

Answer (score 1):

The warning is quite clear on its own.

> warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'wchar_t' to 'const _Elem',
> possible loss of data

Which means, this line `std::string str(wstr.begin(), wstr.end())` involves a type casting from `wchar_t` to a narrower data type `const _Elem` a.k.a `char`. Since any narrowing cast may lead to data loss, hence the warning.

Consider an example as following:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::wstring ws{};
    auto c = (wchar_t)0x41'42'43'44; // A'B'C'D in ASCII

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        ws.push_back(c);

    std::string str{ws.begin(), ws.end()};
    std::cout << str.c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

The code above run and print `DDD`.

On 64 bit machine, the constructor of `str` move 4 bytes at a time to read a `wchar_t`. However, string type can only accept element as `char` ==> the constructor must perform a narrowing cast from `wchar_t` to `char` which results in a loss of 3 byte `A B C` for each `wchar_t` element.